How do I find the arc length of $y=1-e^{-x}$ from $0 \leq x \leq 2$?
I can set up the integral $\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{1+e^{-2x}}\,dx$ by taking the derivative of y and by using the arc length formula. I'm really stuck on how to evaluate this integral. I've tried to follow the steps on symbolab and wolfram alpha but cannot follow them.

Hint: use the change of variables $e^{-2x}=\tan^2(u)$.

Thanks for the hint! I was able to get the answer with that.

Substitute $\tan (t)=e^{-x}$ so that $\sec^2(t)\ \mathrm dt=-e^{-x}\ \mathrm dx$, i.e., $\mathrm dx=-\cot(t)(1+\tan^2(t))\ \mathrm dt=-(\cot(t)+\tan(t))\ \mathrm dt$.
The new limit of integration: $t=\arctan(1)=\frac\pi4$ to $t=\arctan(1/e^2)$.
Now, the arc length is given by:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^2\sqrt{1+e^{-2x}}\ \mathrm dx&=-\int_\frac\pi4^{\arctan(1/e^2)}\sec(t)\left(\cot(t)+\tan(t)\right)\ \mathrm dt\\&=\int_{\arctan(1/e^2)}^\frac\pi4\left(\csc(t)+\sec(t)\tan(t)\right)\ \mathrm dt\\&=\left(\ln|\csc(t)-\cot(t)|+\sec(t)\right)\bigg|_{\arctan(1/e^2)}^\frac\pi4\\&=\ln\left(\sqrt2-1\right)-\ln\left(\sqrt{1+e^4}-e^2\right)+\sqrt2-\frac{\sqrt{1+e^4}}{e^2}\\\int_0^2\sqrt{1+e^{-2x}}\ \mathrm dx&=\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt2-1}{\sqrt{1+e^4}-e^2}\right)+\sqrt2-\frac{\sqrt{1+e^4}}{e^2}\approx2.22142
\end{aligned}$$
Also, see what WolframAlpha says about the integral. It expresses the logarithmic terms in terms of inverse hyperbolic sine functions using the identity $\sinh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$ at $x=-1$ and $-e^2$.
$$\color{blue}{\boxed{\int_0^2\sqrt{1+e^{-2x}}\ \mathrm dx=\sinh^{-1}(e^2)-\sinh^{-1}(1)+\sqrt2-\frac{\sqrt{1+e^4}}{e^2}\approx2.22142}}$$
Hope this helps!

Super detailed and helpful! Thanks!

You're most welcome!

$$I=\int \sqrt{1+e^{-2x}}\,dx$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{2} \log (t-1) \quad \implies \quad I=-\frac 12 \int \frac{\sqrt{t}}{t-1} \,dt$$
$$t=u^2\quad \implies \quad I=\int\frac{u^2}{1-u^2}\,du$$
Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{u^2}{1-u^2}=\frac{1}{2 (u+1)}-\frac{1}{2 (u-1)}-1$$ Now, it is simple. Go back to $x$ and use the given bounds.
